# How to handle escaping user event description in bash script to pass to a sed command?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm fetching an event description from an API using curl and assigning the results to a variable in bash like this:

```
Event=$( curl -s -X GET https://api.vendor.com/v1/events/ev_$API_ID\
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -u 'mykey:' )

EVTITLE=$(echo $Event | jq -r '.name')
DESC=$(echo $Event | jq -r '.description')
```

This is working well so far. But sometimes the EVTITLE or DESC strings have shell special chars in the strings like &, ! and sometimes quotes.

So, later,  when I go to pass the variable to a sed command like this:
(to replace values in a template file)

```
ti_sed="s/EVTITLE/"$EVTITLE"/"
sed -i -e "$ti_sed" filename
```

Where the value in $EVTITLE is something like

Amy does Q&A for you and "other things" !

I'd like to avoid having bash interpret those strings before sed goes to work.
Is there a way to groom the strings so the final sed output looks like the input?
For example can I get the string value of $EVTITLE between single quotes?

Comment: Don’t set or expand `EVTITLE` without double quotes (which you do in the example): `EVTITLE="$(...)"`, `ti_sed="s/EVTITLE/${EVTITLE}/"` etc. You may need to replace (escape) other characters in the string though, such as both forward and back slashes: `EVTITLE="${EVTITLE//\//\\/}"`, `EVTITLE="${EVTITLE//\\/\\\\}"` etc.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek thanks! here's what I would up doing so far: `Desc=$(echo $Event | jq -r '.description')
p_sed='s/\<p\>//g'
ep_sed='s/\<\/p\>//g'
amp_sed='s/\&/+/g;s/amp\;//g'
dquote_sed='s/\"//g'
squote_sed="s/\'//g"
DESC=$(echo $Desc | sed -e "$p_sed;$ep_sed;$amp_sed;$dquote_sed;$squote_sed")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to groom the strings so the final sed output looks
> like the input?

Here's a `bash` demo script which reads strings from a temporary JSON
file into an indexed array and has GNU `sed` write its own conversion
script to edit a template.
Note that `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\u` etc. in the JSON source will be converted
by `jq -r` before `bash` and `sed` see them. The `bash` script reads
newline-delimited lines and **does not work for** JSON strings containing `\n`.

More comments below.

---

```bash
#!/bin/bash
jsonfile="$(mktemp)"  templatefile="$(mktemp)"
# shellcheck disable=SC2064
trap "rm -f -- '${jsonfile}' '${templatefile}'" INT EXIT
cat << 'HERE' > "${jsonfile}"
{
  "Name":"A1",
  "Desc":"*A* \\1 /does/ 'Q&A' for you\tand \"other things\" \\@ $HOME !"
}
HERE
printf '%s\n' '---EVTITLE---' > "${templatefile}"

mapfile -t vars < <(
    jq -r '.Name, .Desc' < "${jsonfile}"
)
wait "$!" || exit   ## abort if jq failed
# shellcheck disable=SC2034
name="${vars[0]}"  desc="${vars[1]}"

printf '%s\n' "${desc}" |
tee /dev/stderr |
sed -e 's/[\\/&\n]/\\&/g' -e 's/.*/s\/EVTITLE\/&\//' | 
tee /dev/stderr |
sed -f /dev/stdin "${templatefile}"
```

These are the 3 lines output by the script (with tabs expanding to
different lengths) showing the contents of:

1. the shell variable `desc`
2. the generated `sed` script
3. the edited template file

```
*A* \1 /does/ 'Q&A' for you and "other things" \@ $HOME !
s/EVTITLE/*A* \\1 \/does\/ 'Q\&A' for you   and "other things" \\@ $HOME !/
---*A* \1 /does/ 'Q&A' for you  and "other things" \@ $HOME !---
```

---

`bash` stores the string it reads and passes it on without modification
using `printf` to `sed` which in turn adds escapes as needed for a
replacement string to be inserted between `s/EVTITLE/` and `/`, i.e.
the `sed` script required to edit the template file.

In *the replacement section* of a `sed` `s`ubstitute command the
following have a special meaning according to
[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

- `\` (backslash) the escape character itself
- the `s` command delimiter, default is `/` but it may be anything
  other than backslash and newline
- `&` (ampersand) referencing the entire matched portion
- `\` ( is one of digits 1 through 9 ) referencing a matched group
- a literal newline

but several `sed`s recognize other escapes as replacements. For example,
GNU `sed` will replace `\f`, `\n`, `\t`, `\v` etc. as in C, and (unless
`--posix` option) its extensions `\L`, `\l`, `\U`, `\u`, and `\E` act
on the replacement.
(More on this by `info sed -n 'The "s" Command'`, `info sed -n Escapes`,
`info sed --index-search POSIXLY_CORRECT`.)

What this means is that all backslash, command delimiter, ampersand,
and newline characters in the input must be escaped, i.e. prefixed with
a backslash, if they are to represent themselves when used in a
replacement section. This is done by asking `sed` to `s/[\\/&\n]/\\&/g`.

Recall that most of the meta characters used in regular expressions
(and the shell, for that matter), such as `^$.*[]{}()`, have no special
meaning when appearing in *the replacement section* of `sed`'s `s`
command and so should not be escaped there. Contrariwise, `&` is not
a regex meta character.